# creating event for IB

Tags: objective-c, events, interface-builder, custom-controls

Is there a way to have a custom control send events that can be used from IB?

Something like the events in UIButton's "sent events" (such us touchUpInside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a custom control send events that can be used
>   from IB?

No. IB "knows" about the events that UIControl implements, but there's no way to tell it about your own events.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, not even with special notification names? How does IB get the events form UIButton? Does IB have a special implementation for every type of control?

Comment: @simpleBob I'm not sure what you mean about a special implementation, but IB knows about all the standard Cocoa and Cocoa Touch user interface objects.